# Couchbase Document ID Requirements and limitations

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-lite

What are the restrictions for a `Couchabse` Document's ID string?

- Length?
- Are special characters allowed?
- What does the string have to start and end with?

[Couchbase Guide Sample Code:](http://developer.couchbase.com/mobile/develop/guides/couchbase-lite/native-api/document/index.html)

```
var properties = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    {"title", "Little, Big"},
    {"author", "John Crowley"},
    {"published", 1982}
};
var document = database.GetDocument("978-0061120053");
Debug.Assert(document != null);
var rev = document.PutProperties(properties);
```

On `var document = database.GetDocument("978-0061120053");` what can be used in place of `"978-0061120053"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from the [Couchbase Developer guide](http://docs.couchbase.com/developer/dev-guide-3.0/keys-values.html) these are the only limits on keys:

> - Keys are strings, typically enclosed by quotes for any given SDK.
> - No spaces are allowed in a key.
> - Separators and identifiers are allowed, such as underscore:       ‘person_93847’.
> - A key must be unique within a bucket; if you attempt to store the       same key in a bucket, it will either overwrite the value or return an 
>     error in the case of add().
> - Maximum key size is 250 bytes. Couchbase Server stores all keys in       RAM and does not remove these keys to free up space in RAM. Take this 
>     into consideration when you select keys and key length for your
>     application.

Comment: The last bullet point isn't actually correct as of Couchbase 3.0 - it now has the "full eviction" mode, which doesn't store all keys and metadata in RAM.

Comment: hmm after reading [this](https://forums.couchbase.com/t/document-id-conventions/303/2?u=can) where he mentions white space only not allowed as first and last char, I just tried white space within the key with no problems so far..could save and bucket.get("my key") using node sdk..any reason it could be bad?

Comment: @Coding_with_Code thought might be an interesting read [why I use :: as separator](https://blog.couchbase.com/key-pattern-delimiter-in-couchbase/)